# Generating $\sigma$-algebra and measure from the Riesz Representation Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, riesz-representation-theorem

Let $\Lambda:C_c(\mathbb R)\to\mathbb R$ be a positive linear functional.

The Riesz representation theorem gives that to construct the measure $\mathcal M$ and $\sigma$-algebra $\mu$, we do the following:

1. For every open set $V\subset\mathbb R$, define $$\mu(V)=\sup\{\Lambda f:f\prec V\}.$$
2. For every $E\subset\mathbb R$, define $$\mu(E)=\inf\{\mu(V):E\subset V,\ V\text{  open}\}.$$
3. Define $\mathcal M$ as the collection of all those $E\subset\mathbb R$ such that $$\mu(E)=\sup\{\mu(K):K\subset E,\ K\text{ compact}\}.$$

Here, $f\prec V$ means that $f\in C_c(\mathbb R)$, $0\leq f\leq 1$, $V$ is open, and $\operatorname{supp}(f)\subset V$.

The whole construction is eluding me.

> Can someone give a specific example of a positive linear functional, and run through the steps of generating $\mathcal M$ and $\mu$?

Many thanks.

Comment: Look at the proof of Theorem 2.20 in Rudin's "Real & Complex Analysis". In that case, $\Lambda$ is essentially the Riemann integral of $f$.

Comment: By the way, it is more correct to refer to this as the Riesz-Markov-Kakutani theorem (in some name order...), because those three all proved the same result at about the same time, but in a world-state that did not encourage communication (not even talking about lack-of-internet).

Comment: In practice one often does not care about any explicit description of the measure and integral, because the only _literal_ integrals one often evaluates are of nicer functions... which completely determines the process (=continuous linear map). From some viewpoint, the only critical issue is _existence_ of an integral-like continuous linear map... continuous in _some_ topology... The problems with $\lim (\int)=\int \lim$ with pointwise limits show that pointwise limits ... fail, despite their seeming naturality. Thus, we must do subtler things to make integration be a continuous functional.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As copper.hat said, theorem 2.20 (and 2.14, though not very funny) of Rudin's real and complex analysis are what you're looking for.

Now i don't know what you already have learned about measures and integration theory but a good way to create measures is the following :

**1)** Selecta pre-measure you like. For the Lebesgue measure it will be the function defined by $\mu_0([a;b[)=b-a$ on the ring $\mathcal R$ of union of left closed right opened intervals. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-measure) for more details.

**2)** Create an Outer measure $\mu^*$ from the pre-measure. This outer measure is defined on **every** subset of the reals as follow

$$\mu^*(A)=\inf\left\{\sum_{i=0}^\infty \mu_0(A_i) : A_i \in \mathcal R \text{ and }A \subset \bigcup_{i=0}^\infty A_i\right\}$$

For the Lebesgue case it'll gives you the Lebesgue outer measure. [This method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_measure#Method_II) also work to create outer measures, it's used in the creation of hausdorrf measures for example.

**3)** Restrict that outer measure to the set $\mathcal M\subset \mathcal P(\mathbf R)$ defined by

$$\mathcal M = \left\{A\in \mathcal P(\mathbf R) : \forall B \in \mathcal P(\mathbf R), \mu^*(A\cap B)+\mu^*(A\backslash  B)=\mu^*(A) \right\}.$$

It can be shown that $\mathcal M$ is a sigma algebra and that $\mu=\mu^*_{|\mathcal M}$ is a measure.

The construction from positive linear functional is just a variation of this process. You have exactly the same steps : constructing some kind of pre-measure, extending it as an outer measure with the same definition i used and finaly restricting this outer measure to a proper subset of $\mathcal P (\mathbf R)$ to obtain a measure.

Now for the specific examples : You can try for yourself to construct the measure obtained with the functional $\Lambda_\alpha(f)=f(\alpha)$ for a fixed $\alpha\in \mathbf R$.

If we take $\displaystyle\Lambda(f)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x) d x$ in the sense of the Riemann integral (not Lebesgue, of course) we will create the Lesbesgue measure. The combination of Urysohn's lemma and the fact that open sets of $\mathbf R^n$ can be written as the countable union of half open boxes shows that it's indeed equivalent to the pre-measure used in **1)** to construct Lebesgue's measure. So it's really the volume of an open set. Once again writting any open set as a countable union of boxes "shows" (but there is a fair amount of details hidden here) that my step **2)** and yours are the same : you get the Lebesgue outer measure. For step 3 you can go read the theorem 2.17 of Rudin's book. You get the Lebesgue measure and sigma algebra in step 3.